# how to use SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, learning

did someone can to refer me to a good site that explain how to use SharePoint 2010?

Comment: Your question is too broad. To be sure you receive answers that match your need, make your question more specific

Answer (score 1):

Very general quesrion, but i think what you need is a link to Technet migration portal for [SharePoint server 2010](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/ee517214) (if you use MOSS) and [SharePoint foundation 2010](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/ee517215) (if you use Windows SharePoint Service 3)